# Django: How to raise an exception when a user submits an unfinished form?

Tags: python, django, forms, error-handling

I've got a relatively standard RegistrationForm that looks like this:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'username'}), initial='')
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'email'}), initial='')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password'}), initial='')
    password_repeat = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'retype password'}), initial='')
```

***How could I create a clean method that returns an error when a user forgets to fill in one or more fields? (ie. "You forgot to fill in the email field")***

I've tried the following two options in my clean() method (I'll use the password and password_repeat fields as examples):

```
password = self.cleaned_data['password']
password_repeat = self.cleaned_data['password_repeat']
# initial values are set to '' for all fields, see above.
if password == '':
    raise forms.ValidationError("You forgot to type in a password.")
elif password_repeat == '':
        raise forms.ValidationError("You forgot to retype your password.")
```

**The first option returns:**

KeyError at /homepage/

'password'

---

```
try:
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    password_repeat = self.cleaned_data['password_repeat']
except KeyError(password):
    raise forms.ValidationError("You forgot to fill in the password field.")
```

**The second option returns:**

UnboundLocalError at /homepage/

local variable 'password' referenced before assignment

---

Bonus points if you can provide a solution that allows for the remaining fields to be checked as well (so that I can return an form bound to the data the user successfully submitted).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required) property available for all Field types, which automatically does this type of validation. So your code would look like:

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'username'}),
        required = True)
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'email'}),
        required = True)
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'password'}),
        required = True)
    password_repeat = forms.CharField(
        widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'placeholder': 'retype password'}),
        required = True)
```

*Note: I think you can leave out those `initial = ''` parameters as well, as shown above.*

I'm actually not sure why you're getting the errors you mentioned in your question, perhaps you could post the relevant code from your `views.py`? It could be because you need to return `cleaned_data` at the end of any `clean` method you implement.

I would also just say that your use of the `clean` method is not quite right. If you refer to this page of the documentation on [form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) you see that to validate a single field you use the specific `clean_<fieldname>` method e.g. `clean_password_repeat`. Using the `clean` method is appropriate when validation involves multiple field simultaneously, one example of this you may like to use is checking the inputs for the two password fields match.

```
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    # field definitions (above)

    def clean(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        password_repeat = self.cleaned_data['password_repeat']
        if password != password_repeat:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"Passwords do not match.")
        return cleaned_data
```

*Note: Code is not tested.*

I hope this was helpful!

Comment: Great answer! I've fixed my clean() method. Also, I removed the `initial = ''`, and added the `required = True`. I'm still getting the `KeyError 'password'` when I leave the password field blank...the location of the error is in RegisterForm's clean() method at the line that reads `password=self.cleaned_data['password']`. Any thoughts?

Comment: **Edit:** When the `username` or `email` fields are left blank, I get the desired `"This field is required."` message. So your solution fixed half the problem.

Comment: Ah, it looks like I wasn't writing my clean() method correctly, and had left out some things relating to cleaned_data. Found the solution here: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other]

Comment: Okay great, sorry if my answer was misleading, I answered right before I went to bed so I didn't really have time to test/check it properly. Good that you got it working though!

Answer (score 1):

Since django 1.2 it is able to write [validation code on model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean). I allways write business rules in model side:

This is your model:

```
from django.db import models
class Issue(models.Model):
    ....

    def clean(self): 
        rules.Issue_clean(self)

#I write business rules into another file ...
def Incidencia_clean( instance ): 
    import datetime as dt

    errors = {}

    #some business rules:     
    if not instance.dia_incidencia: 
        errors.setdefault('b1',[]).append(u'Falten...ranja')

    if not  instance.franja_incidencia: 
        errors.setdefault('b2',[]).append(u'Falten..nja')

    if instance.dia_incidencia < ( dt.date.today() + 
                                   dt.timedelta( days = -7) ): 
        errors.setdefault('b3',[]).append(u'''No es ... setmana)''')

    if instance.getDate() > datetime.now(): 
        errors.setdefault('b4',[]).append(u'''Encara ...itzat.''') 

    if len( errors ) > 0: 
        raise ValidationError(errors)
```

In template:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
      {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        {{error}}
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I prefer to write business rule one time in model than repeat rules into each form.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that steps through the keys in a dict and raises an exception if any of them are mapped to the empty string or any other False-like value. The exception tells you which key in the dict was missing an entry.

```
for key in self.cleaned_data:
    if not self.cleaned_data[key]:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You didn't fill in the {} form".format(key))
```

If you exclusively want to test for empty strings (and not `False`, `0`, `[]`, etc), change `if not self.cleaned_data[key]:` to `if self.cleaned_data[key] == '':`.